Dibujar figuras en sectores dinámicos Javascript
Tengo una ruleta hecha en javascript, este es el ejemplo:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Wheel of Fortune Design Test</title>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    
    canvas {
      border: 2px solid #000;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="wheelCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

  <script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById('wheelCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const rad = canvas.width / 2;
    const sectors = [{
        color: '#FF5733',
        label: 'A'
      },
      {
        color: '#33FF57',
        label: 'B'
      },
      {
        color: '#3357FF',
        label: 'C'
      },
      {
        color: '#FF33A6',
        label: 'D'
      },
      {
        color: '#FFBD33',
        label: 'E'
      }
    ];
    const arc = (2 * Math.PI) / sectors.length;

    sectors.forEach((sector, index) => {
      const ang = arc * index;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = sector.color;
      ctx.moveTo(rad, rad);
      ctx.arc(rad, rad, rad, ang, ang + arc);
      ctx.lineTo(rad, rad);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(rad, rad);
      ctx.rotate(ang + arc / 2);
      ctx.textAlign = "right";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
      ctx.font = "20px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(sector.label, rad - 10, 10);
      ctx.restore();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>



Y el resultado del código es este, es muy básico el diseño, solo es para poner en práctica los dibujos en canvas:

Lo que requiero es que cada sector, dentro de cada uno,  se dibuje un triángulo isósceles de color negro con transparencia  de .4 y se adapte al tamaño del sector, esto con el fin de que agarre cualquier tono de color. quiero hacer algo parecido a esto, pero refiriéndome sólo al triángulo dentro de los sectores de la ruleta, como lo puedo hacer en javascript?:


Matemáticas e imaginación. Dibujar en canvas no es muy diferente a hacerlo en Photoshop u otro programa de dibujo.

Lo que puedes hacer es modificar un poco tu código y seguir con la lógica de beginPath(), lo cual hace que te dibuje un triángulo y al final el círculo.
Aquí dejo el código:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wheel of Fortune Design Test</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
       }
       canvas {
            border: 2px solid #000;
            background-color: #fff;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="wheelCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

    <script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById('wheelCanvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const rad = canvas.width / 2;
        const smallRad = rad * 0.1;  // Radio del círculo pequeño en el centro
        const triangleBaseRad = rad * 0.1;  // Distancia de la base del triángulo desde el centro
        const triangleTipRad = rad * 0.3;  // Distancia de la punta del triángulo desde el centro
        const sectors = [{ 
                          color: '#FF5733', 
                          label: 'A' 
                         },
                         { 
                         color: '#33FF57', 
                         label: 'B' 
                         },
                         { 
                         color: '#3357FF', 
                         label: 'C' 
                         },
                         {
                         color: '#FF33A6', 
                         label: 'D' 
                         },
                         {
                         color: '#FFBD33', 
                         label: 'E' 
                         }
        ];
        const arc = (2 * Math.PI) / sectors.length;

        sectors.forEach((sector, index) => {
            const ang = arc * index;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = sector.color;
            ctx.moveTo(rad, rad);
            ctx.arc(rad, rad, rad, ang, ang + arc);
            ctx.lineTo(rad, rad);
            ctx.fill();

            // Dibujar el triángulo isósceles apuntando hacia afuera
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)'; // Negro con transparencia
            ctx.moveTo(
                rad + triangleBaseRad * Math.cos(ang), 
                rad + triangleBaseRad * Math.sin(ang)
            );
            ctx.lineTo(
                rad + triangleTipRad * Math.cos(ang + arc / 2), // Punta del triángulo ajustado
                rad + triangleTipRad * Math.sin(ang + arc / 2)
            );
            ctx.lineTo(
                rad + triangleBaseRad * Math.cos(ang + arc), 
                rad + triangleBaseRad * Math.sin(ang + arc)
            );
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(rad, rad);
            ctx.rotate(ang + arc / 2);
            ctx.textAlign = "right";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
            ctx.font = "20px Arial";
            ctx.fillText(sector.label, rad - 10, 10);
            ctx.restore();
        });

        // Dibujar el círculo central
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(rad, rad, smallRad, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.fill();
    </script>
</body>
</html>



Saludos!!

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo, me ayudo bastante eso tu logica y lo aplique y le agregue mas triangulos y degradados, gracias de nuevo :)

@Israel, si la respuesta te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, considera votarla y/o marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!
